# Trying to run the RSA SDK under Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat

Java newbie here.

Working on a some java App that uses the RSA SDK 8.2.   All applications work fine when run as a console application.  We're need to put a Web front end on it but we error out as shows below.

We've tried running it on both Wildfly 10 and Tomcat 8.0.  Using Java 1.8

Below is error received when running on Tomcat.  The error of NoSuchMethodException below from org.glassfish.tyrus.server.TyrusServerConfiguration.()

This exists in one of the Jars provided in the SDK.  If we remove the jar Tomcat will serve up the page but will fail when a call to the SDK is made.  If we include the jar, we get the error below.

```
SEVERE: Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing<br>
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.glassfish.tyrus.server.TyrusServerConfiguration<br>
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.glassfish.tyrus.server.TyrusServerConfiguration
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:74)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.glassfish.tyrus.server.TyrusServerConfiguration.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    ... 9 more

Sep 26, 2017 3:00:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/tomcattest3] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Comment: Did you ever find the problem?

Comment: No.  Tried many things, engaged many developers with no success.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem when I add the wlfullclient.jar from SDK 8.2SP1 to my project running on Tomcat 8.0.47.

Comment: Sorry to say we never got it to work and just ended up running it from the command line.  It would have been too expensive to go through the vendor.  Too bad, we could have done a lot with it running it from Tomcat.  Good luck.

Comment: I have the same issue with wlfullclient when trying to run in Jetty. Jetty is trying to call the constructor of TyrusServerConfiguration because it wants to initialize it as an implementation of ServerApplicationConfig. Trying to disable this with some Jetty config, but haven't found a fix yet.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to duplicate this problem using Tomcat 9. I added websocket-ri-bundle-1.1.jar to Tomcat's lib without realizing that it already contained websocket-api-jar. When I removed the ri bundle I no longer got the error.